# Integrating the Hopf invariant for $\pi:S^3\to S^2$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I've been working on the last part of problem 9., chapter 9 in Nakahara's *Geometry, Topology and Physics* all day, with no success, and am in need of some assistance. We are asked to compute the Hopf invariant of $\pi:S^3\to S^2$, where given $S^3 = \{\mathbf x = (x^1,x^2,x^3,x^3)\in\mathbb R \,|\, \|\mathbf x\|=1\}$, and similarly given $S^2$ (where we write the points as $(\xi^1,\xi^2,\xi^3)$), the map $\pi$ is defined by 
$$\xi^1=2(x^1x^3+x^2x^4)\\
\xi^2=2(x^2x^3-x^1x^4)\\
\xi^3=(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2-(x^3)^2-(x^4)^2.$$

But consider for now just some general $f:S^{2n-1}\to S^n$. Let $\Omega_n$ be a volume form on $S^n$ normalized to 1, and consider its pullback $f^*\Omega_n$. We verify it is closed and can be written as $f^*\Omega_n=d\omega_{n-1}$, $\omega_{n-1}\in \Omega^{n-1}(S^{2n-1})$.
The Hopf invariant is defined as $$H(f)\equiv \int_{S^{2n-1}}\omega_{n-1}\wedge\mathrm d \omega_{n-1}.$$

After a few more questions, we are asked to compute $H(\pi)$, with $n=2$.

My approach was to take the god given volume element $vol_{\mathbb R^3}=\mathrm d\xi^1\wedge\mathrm d\xi^2\wedge\mathrm d\xi^3$ and take the interior product with a vector field everywhere normal to the 2-sphere, $N=\sum_i \xi^i\partial_{\xi^i}$, to obtain the volume form on $S^2$, $$vol_{S^2}=\xi^1 \mathrm d\xi^2\wedge\mathrm d\xi^3-\xi^2 \mathrm d\xi^1\wedge\mathrm d\xi^3+\xi^3 \mathrm d\xi^1\wedge\mathrm d\xi^2.$$

I don't care about the normalization yet so I take this to be $\Omega_2$. However, when I pull it back with $\pi$ the result is horribly long, and I won't even post it here. After that, I have, modulo my own errors in arithmetic, the result $\mathrm d \omega_1$, but I also need $\omega_1$. Everything just seems hopeless. I could get it by solving a system of PDEs but that seems also inaccessible.

I found a similar calculation in *Topology for physicists* by Schwarz and Levy, p.165:

[image]

The (7.4.1) they mention is just the integral definition of the invariant, whereas (6.3.1) is a volume form for the n-sphere $$\omega = \frac{1}{(1+\sum (x^i)^2)^n} \mathrm dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm dx^n.$$

They haven't specified $f:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ anywhere, and their entire calculation is unclear to me. How did they get the one-form $\sigma$? In one of the questions, we are asked to prove that the invariant does not depend on the choice of $\omega_{n-1}$ - so did the authors simply take $d\omega_{n-1}$ to be the volume form (6.3.1) on the 2-sphere in spherical coordinates? Still, how did they get $\omega_1=\sigma$? Can anyone explain?

And, again, is the direct approach that Nakahara asks even doable? Or does it need to be a bit more indirect :)

Comment: $S^2$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb CP^1$ and if we can take $\omega$ our volume form on $S^2$ as the Fubini-Study form (normalized), this calculation becomes much simpler.  See exercise 3.2 here https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/symp-ex3.pdf .

Comment: I tried something with the Fubini-Study form, but I may have dismissed it too early, thank you!

Comment: I recently read of review of Bott and Tu's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" by Jim Stasheff. From the review : "The treatment of the Hopf invariant of the Hopf map ... is a particularly fine example of the combination of integral methods (e.g., the linking number definition) and form methods (e.g., the functorial exterior product definition). This suggests to me that this would be a good place to look to see a detailed explanation of this calculation.

Comment: By the way, how to prove the part (c) of this problem, namely $H(f)=H(g)$ if $f$ is homotopic to $g$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I will be answering my question for the benefit of people who may search for this exact thing in the future. I appreciate PVAL's valuable comments. In the end, it seems I had to simplify the volume form a bit - after that it all worked out.

First of all, I normalize the form $vol_{S^2}$ from my question 
$$\Omega_2=\frac{1}{4\pi}(\xi^1 \mathrm d\xi^2\wedge\mathrm d\xi^3-\xi^2 \mathrm d\xi^1\wedge\mathrm d\xi^3+\xi^3 \mathrm d\xi^1\wedge\mathrm d\xi^2)$$
and note that, since $(\xi^1)^2+(\xi^2)^2+ (\xi^3)^2=1$, we have
$$\xi^1\mathrm d \xi^1+\xi^2\mathrm d \xi^2+\xi^3\mathrm d \xi^3=0$$
which we can use to eliminate for example $\mathrm d\xi^3$ on any open set $\subset S^2$ where $\xi^3\neq0$. 
We find that
$$\Omega_2=\frac{1}{4\pi\xi^3}\,\mathrm d\xi^1\wedge\mathrm d\xi^2,$$
which is much easier to pullback. After lengthy calculation, and using the same thing as before, $$\mathrm d x^4=-\frac{1}{x^4}\sum_{i=1}^3 x^i \mathrm d x^i,$$
we get $$-\pi\cdot f^*\Omega_2=\mathrm dx^1\wedge\mathrm dx^2+\frac{x^1}{x^4}\cdot\mathrm dx^1\wedge\mathrm dx^3+\frac{x^2}{x^4}\cdot\mathrm dx^2\wedge\mathrm dx^3. $$

The first term is $\mathrm d ( x^1 \mathrm d x^2).$ To find the other two, we want to find some $\tilde\omega\in\Omega^1(S^3)$ such that $\mathrm d\tilde\omega=(\frac{x^1}{x^4}\cdot\mathrm dx^1+\frac{x^2}{x^4}\cdot\mathrm dx^2)\wedge\mathrm dx^3$, so we try $\tilde\omega=f(x^1,x^2,x^3)\mathrm dx^3$. This means we have to solve $$\partial_{x^1}f=\frac{x^1}{x^4}=\frac{x^1}{\sqrt{1-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2-(x^3)^2}}$$
and the same but with $x^1\leftrightarrow x^2.$ The solution is obviously $f=-\sqrt{1-(x^1)^2-(x^2)^2-(x^3)^2}$. To get this, we had to say $x^4\mapsto +\sqrt{1-\dots}$, and this choice of the plus sign in front of the radical is valid only on open covers of $S^3$ disjoint from the ones on which we take the negative sign (since we are using a chart on which $x^4\neq0$). But, the opposite choice also reverses the sign of the solution, so we can write in general $\tilde\omega= -x^4 \mathrm d x^3.$

Therefore, $\omega_1=-\frac{1}{\pi}(x^1 \mathrm d x^2 - x^4 \mathrm d x^3)$, and $$\omega_1\wedge\mathrm d\omega_1=\frac{1}{\pi^2}(x^1 \mathrm dx^2\wedge\mathrm dx^3\wedge\mathrm dx^4-x^4 \mathrm dx^1\wedge\mathrm dx^2\wedge\mathrm dx^3).$$
Now from symmetry, $$H(\pi)=\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{S^3}x^1 \mathrm dx^2\wedge\mathrm dx^3\wedge\mathrm dx^4.$$
To calculate the integral we can use spherical coordinates:

$$x^1=\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\sin{\gamma} \\
x^2=\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\cos{\gamma} \\
x^3=\sin{\alpha}\cos{\beta} \\
x^4=\cos{\alpha} $$

where $\gamma\in(0,2\pi)$ and $\alpha,\beta\in(0,\pi)$. So, we calculate!

$$\int_{S^3}x^1 \mathrm dx^2\mathrm dx^3\mathrm dx^4=\int \sin^4{\alpha}\sin^3{\beta}\sin^2{\gamma}\:\mathrm d\alpha\mathrm d\beta \mathrm d\gamma=\frac{3\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}.$$

Thus, finally, $H(\pi)=1.$